# Reticulation Controller

Tags: timer, control-system

I'm thinking of building my own reticulation controller to drive an automatic watering system. Does anyone out there have a good circuit diagram? A simple 6 or 8 station control with adjustable timer and a 'GO' button would do nicely! Then I can push said 'GO' button and the stations would then come on in sequence for the selected time and automatically cycle until finished.

Comment: This question needs to be heavily updated.  It's very, very vague in its current state.  What sort of outputs do you need to drive?  How do the outputs need to be sequenced?  How does the device need to be powered?

Comment: To respond to the above comment, I thought it was obvious from the question being for a reticulation controller that it would drive reticulation valves. Most people count from 1 to 8, so I would make the valve sequence travel from output 1 and count up. Most people power things like this with electricity! Batteries wouldn't last so transformed mains power is a given. As [Michael Karas](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/12135/michael-karas) said below, most garden valves work off 24V, so that would be a good start.

Comment: If you're going to be a douche when someone asks you for more detail, maybe you should try another site to get answers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search for "sprinkler controller". Your system will need to have an MCU of some type with a display or LEDs plus an array of triac components that can switch the valves on and off. Most sprinkler and irrigation type valves operate off 24VAC.

You may want to investigate the OpenSprinkler project.

[image]

[Rayshobby LLC](http://rayshobby.net/?page_id=160)

Comment: A bit more complicated than what I was looking for, but will deffinatelly do the job!